# How to convert "dd:hh:mm:ss" format to numeric type On Excel?

Tags: excel, text, time, numeric

With the columns 'start at" , "end at" , I know the 'ride length' which I get from D-C in *hh:min:sec* format.I also found in *day:hour:min:sec* format by **=TEXT(D12-C12,"d:h:mm:ss"**) formula.
**This is in a text format**, **I** **want it to be a** **numeric format** so that I can find min,max,avg ride length.

I tried the several solutions like  [converting text to numeric](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/convert-numbers-stored-as-text-to-numbers-40105f2a-fe79-4477-a171-c5bad0f0a885).This is not working.

| C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| start_at | end_at | ride_length(hour:min:sec) | ride_length(day:hour:min:sec) |
| 31-10-2021 11:38:30 PM | 03-11-2021 3:53:21 PM | 64:14:51 | 2:16:14:51 |
| 31-10-2021 11:47:46 PM | 02-11-2021 12:47:42 AM | 24:59:56 | 1:00:59:56 |

Comment: _I want it to be a numeric format_ - then don't use `Text`.  The dates were already numeric [date time serial numbers](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm) before that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using excel it is not necessary to use the TEXT formula to express the number of days. Instead place the result of the D-C subtraction and change the cell format to d "d" h "h" m "m" s "s" (see Figure 1)

[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmBJz.png)

Comment: thank you @William Escobar Garcia.It worked

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/q/70457948/14652541]..can you solve it also?