# How to swap cell values based on a condition In Excel?

Tags: excel

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **start_time** | **end_time** | **duration** |
| 01-09-2021 6:45:38 PM | 01-09-2021 6:45:24 PM | ##### |
| 01-09-2021 6:42:09 PM | 01-09-2021 6:41:40 PM | ##### |
| 28-09-2021 1:53:18 AM | 28-09-2021 2:00:02 AM | 00:06:44 |

Duration is calculated by subtraction (B-A).But **In some cells I have A>B .Then the duration cant be calculated.**
I want to interchange the cell values where A>B.**In roughly,If A>B then,A=B and B=A.otherwise The cell will be remain unchanged.**
How Can I do it in excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply try below formula then apply desired date/time format to resulting cell.

```
=IF(A2>B2,A2-B2,B2-A2)
```

In case of only time you may use below formula to return times only.

```
 =IF(IF(A2>B2,A2-B2,B2-A2)>=1,TEXT(IF(A2>B2,A2-B2,B2-A2),"dd/mm/e hh:mm:ss"),TEXT(IF(A2>B2,A2-B2,B2-A2),"hh:mm:ss"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be using `ABS`, like so:

```
=ABS(A2-B2)
```

So, regardless of the order, the duration will be positive.

The only thing left to do is format e.g. 0.99984 to a Time format.
If you end up with a duration greater than 1, that means 24 hours (1 day).

So, you could also get the number of days and the hours by:

```
=ROUNDDOWN(C2;0) -- To get whole days

=MOD(C2;ROUNDDOWN(C2;0)) -- To get the time (Hours, Minutes, Seconds)
```

*Hope this was helpful!* ^_^